# What does ENDOFMENU do?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have been given an example program, I am wondering what exactly the `<<ENDOFMENU` and `ENDOFMENU` does, won't it work the same if you leave it out and just use the while loop?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Menu test program...";
stop=0;
while test $stop -eq 0; do
cat<<ENDOFMENU
1: print the date
2,3 : print the current working directory
4: exit
ENDOFMENU
  echo; echo -e "your choice?\c"
  read reply
echo
case $reply in
    "1")
       date
;;
    "2"|"3")
       pwd
;;
    "4")
      stop=1
;;
    *)
      echo illegal choice
  esac
done
```

Comment: This question may be better located at http://stackoverflow.com/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ENDOFMENU` as used in your example is a so-called [*here document*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) or *here doc*. It allows for a multi-line string without needing to escape quoting characters such as `'` and `"`.

Quoting the [`bash(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1) manual:

> This  type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current
>   source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing blanks) is seen.
>   All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a
>   command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> <<[-]word
> here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname
>   expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word are  quoted,  the 
>   delimiter  is  the  result  of  quote removal on word, and the lines in the 
>   here-document are not expanded.  If word is unquoted, all lines of the 
>   here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and 
>   arithmetic  expansion.   In  the latter case, the character sequence \<newline>
>   is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.

You showed the following code in your example:

```
cat<<ENDOFMENU
1: print the date
2,3 : print the current working directory
4: exit
ENDOFMENU
  echo; echo -e "your choice?\c"
```

That makes a string available as stream and then prints them to the console using the `cat` command. Finally, it prints another blank line followed by the string `your choice?` and an escape sequence that means "produce no further output" and effectively strips the newline that would follow. It could be rewritten as:

```
echo -e "    1: print the date
2,3 : print the current working directory
4: exit

your choice?\c"
```